# Crop Image C# Distorsion

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to crop an image with C# but i have some problem.

I need to crop this image and remove 15 pixels from top:

I have used this code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(outputFileName);
Rectangle destRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 15),
new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height));
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height - 15);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, destRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
bmp.Save(outputFileNameCut, ImageFormat.Png);
```

This is the first image quality with a zoom:

[image]

and this the second:

[image]

How can i have the same image quality?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are grabbing a rectangle higher than what fits in the bitmap (the second `Size` parameter is the size, not the bottom-right coordinates), so it's scaling it:

```
Rectangle destRectangle = new Rectangle(
       new Point(0, 15), new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height-15));
```

This should work... since it's not actually the `dest` rectangle, but the `source` rectangle on the `DrawImage` call

Other way to crop, which doesn't even need a `Graphics` object might be:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(outputFileName);
Rectangle srcRectangle = new Rectangle(
       new Point(0, 15), new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height-15));
Bitmap croppedBitmap = myBitmap.Clone(srcRectangle, myBitmap.PixelFormat);
croppedBitmap.Save(outputFileNameCut, ImageFormat.Png);
```

If you use this method, make 100% sure that the crop rectangle doesn't cross the bounds of the original image, since `Clone` will throw an exception if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try to paste

```
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

before calling DrawImage

or use

```
g.DrawImageUnscaled(myBitmap, new Point(0, -15));
```

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Whereas both methods work, I'd say the second makes much more sense. Changing the interpolation mode and smoothing will avoid aliasing, but the problem is drawing it scaled in first place, which is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org) framework. It can handle this easily using .Quality() method.